# How can I parse markdown asynchronously using unified and remark-parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, markdown, remarkjs

I want to parse markdown in the browser and do that ansyc, so nothing "hangs".
However, the unified `parse` function is only synchronous. So, how to parse Markdown without blocking the browser/UI?

My code:

```
import { unified } from "unified";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";

const tree = unified().use(remarkParse).parse(markdown);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-blocking browser scripts you could take a look at Service Workers. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) for details. With workers, there will no (or close-to) changes in the code. It you need to pass information between the *primary page* and the *worker* you need to pass so-called messages between each of them (`postMessage`/`onmessage`, see examples on the mentioned docs page).

tl;dr: Web Workers are background threads for js code that's running aside of the default js cycle of the tab (also possible if the tab is closed).

Comment: accepted this one as it was the *first* one who brought up service workers that I didn't know yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **process** method provided by [unified](https://github.com/unifiedjs/unified), which returns a Promise.

```
import { unified } from "unified";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";
import remarkRehype from "remark-rehype";
import rehypeStringify from "rehype-stringify";

const parseMarkdown = async (markdown) => {
  const result = await unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkRehype)
    .use(rehypeStringify)
    .process(markdown);

  return result.toString();
};

(async () => {
  const markdown = "# Hello, World!";
  const html = await parseMarkdown(markdown);
  console.log(html);
})();
```

Define an **async** function **parseMarkdown** that takes a markdown string as input. use unified with **[remarkParse](https://unifiedjs.com/explore/package/remark-parse/)**, **remarkRehype**, and **rehypeStringify** to process the markdown asynchronously inside the function. The process method returns a Promise, which we can await to get the result. Now convert the result to a string with the `toString()` method.

You can then use an **async immediately invoked function expression** **(IIFE)** to call the parseMarkdown function.

```
(async () => {
  const markdown = "# Hello, World!";
  const html = await parseMarkdown(markdown);
  console.log(html);
})();
```

Comment: That won't work for me, I need to access the tree that parse returns. Process returns no tree structure.

Comment: You can use the run method provided by unified, which returns a Promise that resolves to the syntax tree.

Comment: with `run` VS Code also shows mit that awaiot has no effect. Can you give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use worker that parses Markdown in another thread using `postMessage`:

`index.js` (main file):

```js
let mdParseWorker = new Worker("./worker.js");

mdParseWorker.onmessage = e => {
  let tree = e.data;
  // Do something with tree
}

mdParseWorker.postMessage(markdown, "*")
```

`worker.js`:

```js
import { unified } from "unified";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";

onmessage = e => {
  let tree = unified().use(remarkParse).parse(e.data);
  self.postMessage(tree, "*");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code sample :-)